# можно ли выполнять запрос SELECT в WHERE

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE id = 10 AND user.limit > COUNT(
    SELECT id 
    FROM order 
    WHERE user.id = order.id)
```

Вот такой запрос примером

Comment: Да, вполне себе можно. В UPDATE такой SELECT может быть запрещен, если у движка появляются подозрения, что замешана обновляемая таблица.

Comment: проще всего взять и попробовать. можно или нет - зависит от конкретной реализации SQL. MySQL - не единственный существующий SQL Server.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью SQL вы можете вкладывать запросы внутрь друга друга. Обычно, внутренний запрос генерирует значение которое проверяется в предикате внешнего запроса, определяющего верно оно или нет. Например, предположим что мы знаем им продавца: Motika, но не знаем значение его пол snum, и хотим извлечь все порядки из таблицы Порядков. Имеется один способ чтобы сделать это( вывод показывается в Рисунке 10.1 ):

```
SELECT * 
   FROM Orders 
   WHERE snum = 
       ( SELECT snum 
            FROM Salespeople 
            WHERE sname = 'Motika');
```

источник: http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch10.shtml

Comment: а COUNT() можно как моем запросе?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант возможен:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE id = 10 AND user.limit > (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM order 
    WHERE user.id = order.id)
```